# draw the app under the status bar in react native

Tags: react-native, ios11, statusbar, ios10.3

"react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.22",
"react-native": "0.50.1", XCODE 9.0
My React Native app on iOS 10.3 starts from under the status bar but in iOS 11 the app starts from below the status bar. I want to start the app from 0x 0y of screen for all versions of iOS and the nav bar under the status bar. In Android there is a function called `setTranslucent()` but on iOS I didn't find a function which supports this.
In my index.ios.js

```
render() {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);
    StatusBar.setTranslucent(true)
    StatusBar.setHidden(true)
    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1,backgroundColor:BACKGROUND,}}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <Provider  store={store}>
            <RouterComponent />
          </Provider>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>

    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `<StatusBar hidden={true} />` or `<StatusBar hidden />` to hide status bar?

Comment: yes tried in index.ios.js